# Prevent maximize from task manager (WPF application)

Tags: c#, wpf

I read some answers on how to prevent maximizing of an WPF app, and most of them work.

```
     ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
```

works ok.

However, a user is still able to go to the Task manager and maximize a window from there:

[image]

and this causes some problems.

One proposed solution is to listen to `StateChanged` event, like so:

```
this.StateChanged += new System.EventHandler((sender, eventArgs) =>
{
   if (this.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized)
   {
      this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
   }
}
```

this also works, but it gives like a 'blickering' animation, window goes to top left corner, and then immediately returns to it's original position. So in a way, it works, but it's not nice on the eyes.

Is there any way to handle state change event before it is executed? Something like `BeforeStateChange`

Comment: I think that without P-invoke this can be impossible:/

Comment: Sorry for posting unhelpful comments, but I wouldn't really be concerned about being "nice on the eyes" when the user decides to go great lengths (TaskManager) to overcome your intended layout. You should rather decide whether the user is in the wrong trying to maximize your window (hint: the user is never wrong, but often clueless!) or if you are wrong for deciding on a window size that doesn't play nice with the users windows setting of extra large fonts.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to explicitly set the maximum window size. Since `CanMinimize` mode implies that you cannot resize the window, you can just restrict it's size like that:

```
<Window
    MaxHeight="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    MaxWidth="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <!-- ... -->
</Window>
```